# How to make "ls -1" to print out in quotation marks in combination with xargs?

Tags: ls, xargs

I do an `ls` command like this to list multiple directories. Please be aware of the blank space in the folder `X y`.

```
ls -1d 2021*/"X y"/foobar
```

Output is

```
'20211121-161518-801/X y/foobar'
'20211128-151513-585/X y/foobar'
'20211130-170001-724/X y/foobar'
```

It looks like that ls still use quotation marks here. But when I use this output in combination with `xargs` the quotation marks seams to be lost

```
ls: Zugriff auf '20211121-161518-801/X' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
ls: Zugriff auf 'y/foobar' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

The xargs command is like this

```
ls -1d 2021*/"X y"/foobar | xargs ls
```

In the end I will use a `xargs rm -rf` but the `xargs ls` is just a test.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why \*not\* parse \`ls\` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: In this case you should just do `rm -rf  2021*/"X y"/foobar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Stéphane Chazelas gave you generaly pretty good and deep dive into "modern" `ls`, not all `ls`es are created equal. Even if new GNU `ls` will have `--zero` it will take decades until trickles down everywhere, and this still will not work on all, especially non-GNU based systems.

General consensus with `ls` is that it's meant for human consuption and should not really be trusted for anything else.

Despite this being quite a common knowledge among elder admins, neophytes and novice admins are for many understandable (and other inexplicable) reasons still drawn exclusively to `ls`. As Linux proliferates beyond niche and into more and more mainstream and nationalized environments, this `ls` love is becoming grave problem (as your own situation proves). That is also the reason why GNU `ls` is growing "fast" the options that any `ls` should have had for decades.

However if you really want to solve this problem reliably and safely right now and proper the right tool for this job is `find` command: either used as zero separated list generator, or as direct command executor.

Using `find` as zero separated list generator:

```
find topdir -mindepth 1 [-maxdepth 2] -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I@ stat @
```

Using `find` as direct executor:

```
find topdir -mindepth 1 [-maxdepth 2] -type d -exec stat '{}' \;
```

With `-mindpeth`/`-maxdepth`you can control depth into which the `find` will descend, with `-type` you control which objects it will process. You can also match on object name or even object path. Because `find` does not mangle or escape the object names in any "smart" way by default, you can them pass theses anmes around raw and without fear, either through pipe (generator) or as a part of argv vector (executor).

Just remember when shuffling lists through pipes this way, `-print0` has always to be used, so that names are zero separated, and others characters like spaces and newlines can be expressed directly and don't confuse the reader.

Comment: Note that `-mindepth`, `-maxdepth`, `-print0`, `-0`, are all non-standard GNU extensions. `stat` is a non-standard command for which there exist several incompatible implementations. GNU `find` has a `-printf` predicate that renders `stat` redundant. Also note that sorting file lists reliably even with GNU `find` is particularly painful. So while using `find`, when your' eon a GNU system, can get you a long way, it will be nowhere as convenient or straightforward as when using `zsh` or a proper programming language like perl/python...

Comment: Indeed @StéphaneChazelas, all the points you make are valid, but:
  -  I used `stat` here solely just as an examle "payload" for @buhtz command (it could have been `echo`, I hope this not lost on advanced readers)
  - missing `-print0` can often be emulated by `-printf "xxx\0"`
  - you will often find `-mindepth`, `-maxdepth` on many more oses, than GNU `ls` features, same with `-0`, all three are quite common even on many bsds
  - you can avoid all "separator" spelunking when using executor mode
  - and yes, sorting is the last remaining "issue", but is inherent to unix

Comment: Should I edit my answer?

Comment: Naturally as already said, proper shell (like zsh) or programming language makes you trade all the issues mentioned so far, for other set of your "new" programming issues. In my experience as mentioned, `find` is usually "last" stop before bringing up heavyweight tools like `lua`, `perl` or `python` etc, and tail is quite long on this one. I used it to process hundredths thousands of files and terabytes of data with weird names without a glitch.

Comment: Note that while `-print0` is now pretty common, `-printf` is still GNU specific. `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` would be the standard equivalent. But generally, to handle NUL delimited lists you need GNU implementations of standard utilities (`sed -z`, `sort -z`, `head -z`, `ls --zero`...).

Answer (score 2):

The GNU implementation of `ls` has a `--quoting-style` options which let you specify a quoting style, but none of them is compatible with the quoting style expected by `xargs`.

`xargs` (introduced by PWB Unix in the late 70s) quoting style is similar to that of the Mashey shell (also from PWB Unix), a predecessor of the Bourne shell.

`ls --quoting-style=shell-always` quotes with single quotes as per the Bourne/POSIX shell style, with single quotes themselves entered as `\'`. `xargs` supports both `'...'` and `"..."` in addition to backslash but quoted strings cannot include newline characters which can only be escaped with backslash.

The POSIX `xargs` specification also expects `xargs` to parse the input as text in the current locale and also does not guarantee it will work for arguments larger than 256 bytes, so in general can't be used to process arbitrary data.

The really only reliable way to use `xargs` is with the `-0` option found in some implementations such as GNU `xargs` (you also generally want to use the `-r` option, also non-standard).

The next version of GNU `ls` will have a `--zero` option to output files NUL-delimited, so then you'll be able to do:

```
ls -t --zero | xargs -r0 printf ' * %s\n'
```

For instance.

For now, what you can do is use the `--quoting-style=shell-always` mode to pass that list to a shell, and that shell to convert it to a NUL-delimited list:

```
(
   echo 'files=('
   ls --quoting-style=shell-always -t
   echo '); print -rNC1 -- $files'
) | zsh | xargs -r0 some command
```

But if you're already using `zsh`, you don't really need `ls` nor `xargs` as `zsh` can sort its globs by other criteria like `ls` and has a `stat` builtin to retrieve file metadata (the only reasons you may want to use `ls`) and its own `zargs` command.

In any case, in:

```
ls -d -- *.txt
```

It's the shell that expands `*.txt` to the list of matching files. `ls` is pretty useless there as it just ends up printing them.

You might as well pass the glob expansion to something that can print the list NUL-delimited, such as the `print` builtin in `zsh`:

```
print -rNC1 -- *.txt(N)
```

(here also using the `N`ullglob qualifier, so it prints nothing if the glob doesn't match any file).

Or in the `bash` shell (sometimes still used on GNU systems as that's the GNU shell):

```
print0() {
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf '%s\0' "$@"
}
shopt -s nullglob
print0 *.txt
```